# Python tkinter: address buttons by using a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to minimize my code from this:

```
btn_goto_Sell_A.config(state="normal")
btn_goto_Sell_B.config(state="normal")
btn_goto_Sell_C.config(state="normal")
btn_goto_Buy_A.config(state="normal")
btn_goto_Buy_B.config(state="normal")
btn_goto_Buy_C.config(state="normal")
```

To this:

```
def Enable_Button():
    List = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
    ]
    for Letter in List:
        btn_goto_Sell_Letter.config(state="normal")
        btn_goto_Buy_Letter.config(state="normal")
```

How can i properly talk to my button by building it via my list at the same time?
The idea is, instead of writing the same button config, that its just my list and my for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

The smart thing to do is replace your individual variables with a dictionary:

```
btn_sell = {
    "A": Button(...),
    "B": Button(...),
    "C": Button(...),
}
btn_buy = {
    "A": Button(...),
    "B": Button(...),
    "C": Button(...),
}
```

Then it becomes trivial to loop over the buttons:

```
for label in ("A", "B", "C"):
    btn_sell[label].configure(state="normal")
    btn_buy[label].configure(state="normal")
```

Comment: I made it work like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a the `eval()` function in python:

The following is an example that packs 4 buttons onto the screen in a similar scenario to the one described. the `.pack()` can easily be substituted with the `.config()`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

buy_A = Button(root, text = "Buy A")
buy_B = Button(root, text = "Buy B")
sell_A = Button(root, text = "Sell A")
sell_B = Button(root, text = "Sell B")

buttons = ["A","B"]
for letter in buttons:
    eval(f"buy_{letter}.pack()")
    eval(f"sell_{letter}.pack()")

root.mainloop()
```

Another method would be putting all the button objects in a list, and interacting with them directly via the `for` loop:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

buy_A = Button(root, text = "Buy A")
buy_B = Button(root, text = "Buy B")
sell_A = Button(root, text = "Sell A")
sell_B = Button(root, text = "Sell B")

buttons = [buy_A, buy_B, sell_A, sell_B]
for button in buttons:
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `eval` is the last thing to try in this situation and there is no need, using dictionaries (or lists) is way better (for example because they don't clutter the namespace)